# Circular button with shadow like 5.0 FAB

Tags: android, android-xml, android-button, material-design

I want a button in circular shape with shadow. Shadow must be like FAB. Currently I'm using a png to implement the button.

[image]

But when I use this image I can't give correct pressed state changes.
Is there any way to impleament this by using xml

Comment: Have you did it? I have same problem. if you did it please update your solution. Tks you!

Comment: Well, I ended up using 2 different images with shadow and without. Not the perfect solution though.

Comment: I find a solution, I post it in answer. Can you try this? I think it's good

Answer (score 20):

you can try it

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#00CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

```js
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_circle"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create circle.xml  under `drawable` folder

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#03ae3c"/>
</shape>
```

set this as background for layout or view.  then assign `elevation` attribute to your view. that will give you visual appearance of its shadow.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:elevation="14dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help to design different size and shape or colorfull control in android used following code

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >       <corners android:radius="14dp"/>
        <gradient android:angle="45"
            android:centerX="35%"
            android:centerColor="#7995A8"
            android:startColor="#E8E8E8"
            android:endColor="#000000"
            android:type="linear"/>
        <padding android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp"/>
        <size android:width="270dp"
        android:height="60dp"
        />
        <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#878787"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you create a file name `round_shape.xml` in layout folder with content as

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size android:width="100dp"
                android:height="100dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#59d5fe"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Then in your activity_main.xml (where you want to put the button) adds the code

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@layout/round_shape"
    android:textColor="#f8fdf9" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix size in view layout ex: if you are using this for linearlayout background set say height = 100sp and widht = 100sp

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#00CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```